# When I click on navigation bar, my app goes to previous view

Tags: ios, xcode, uinavigationbar

I have a strange problem with my application.
my view has a navigation bar with a back button on it.
When I click button, it obviously goes to previous view; anyway, today I noticed that it does even if I click in a small area outside the button but very close to it, on navigation bar.

This seems so weird and incomprehensible that I'm beginning to think that it may depend on Simulator iOS that Xcode uses to simulate, run and test application.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: try to color the background of button, you will notice the actual size it is displaying

Comment: back button has a different color from navigation bar, so i'm sure not to click it

Answer (score 0):

The canvas of the `button` is larger than the button itself ,  you could try swipe to left and see that you'll pop the `viewcontroller` as well.

Comment: hi, thanks for answer. my back button was automatically generated, since there' a navigation controller at the beginning of storyboards.so, how could i swipe it leftwards? i just changed its color programmatically, i don't think this may have influenced its behavior. thanks for help

Comment: yeah, I know it is automatically created by pushing a viewController

Comment: and how can i swipe to left? sorry, i know that question may seem stupid, but i'm just a newbie :)

Comment: drag the finger on the navigation bar to the left , if you don't know how swipe works :)

Comment: i'm not using the application, i'm "making the application":))). so i want to eliminate this strange effect from my application, i don't want the user to experience it. how can i do it in Xcode? thanks

Comment: you can remove the gesture recognizers from the UINavigationBar.  for(UIGestureRecognizer *gest in self.navigationController.navigationBar.gestureRecognizers)
    {
        [self.navigationController.navigationBar removeGestureRecognizer:gest];
    }

Comment: i did it, in my viewDidLoad methods, but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: do it in viewWillAppear. and if you plan on removing that small touch from the back button , i don't think it will work.

Comment: i did it, but nothing changed. back button has a different color from navigation bar, so i'm sure not to click it.

Comment: so what actually happens then?

Comment: when i click very close to button on navigation bar, button gets pressed and relative action in triggered (in this case, popping previous view from stack). in fact, i experienced that the same happens when clicking close to the other button that i placed manually on the right of bar, from storybook, to which a custon IBAction will be attached later on

Comment: leave it like that you can't do anything besides removing the swipe gesture.

Comment: previously, i experienced to be unable to change back button color until i explicitly wrote some code in AppDelegate, forcing the app to have always the same style.
is it possible to do the same for removing gesture recognizers? do you know how to do it in AppDelegate?

Comment: Do it in the rootviewcontroller of your uinavigationcontroller instead.

Comment: so, should i define a controller extending uinavigationcontroller, setting it as my root controller's class?
then, i put the code for erasing gesture recognizer in which method inside the class?

Comment: just erase the gesture recognizer in the first viewcontroller and it should propagate in all that are pushed by that viewcontroller.

Comment: well, i did two things: i created a navigationController class extending UINavigationController, put in its viewDidLoad method the code to remove recognizer, set the class as the one governing my navigation controller (which is my root controller, too), but it didn't work. then i tried to do it in the first storyboard after navigation controller, but nothing changer as well. this problem seems harder than expected

Comment: what about writing an empty delegate function managing the event of clicking on navigation bar? in such a way, every time i click it's invoked, but nothing happens. the question is: shouldn't this be the default behavior? i should be able to add recognition only when required. anyway i don't understand why touches trigger the actions associated to closest button

Comment: I think you shouldn't concern yourself with this insignificant issues, this behavior is common in every Apple app that has navigation so don't worry.